# c++ accessing private members causes seg fault

Tags: c++

I'm writing a game in C++.
I have come across an error, the source of which I have yet to discover.

Whenever I try to access private members of the CollisionEngine class I take a seg fault.
By this using commands like this->is_previous_collision_x in one of the member functions of CollisionEngine.

Here is the valgrind output:

```
==23949== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==23949== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==23949== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==23949== Command: ./main
==23949== 
==23949== Thread 2:
==23949== Syscall param writev(vector[...]) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==23949==    at 0x5CCB84D: ??? (in /usr/lib/libc-2.22.so)
==23949==    by 0x72E7DA8: ??? (in /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0)
==23949==    by 0x72E819C: ??? (in /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0)
==23949==    by 0x72E8224: xcb_writev (in /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0)
==23949==    by 0x6FDD18D: _XSend (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==23949==    by 0x6FDD681: _XReply (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==23949==    by 0x6FC8406: XInternAtom (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==23949==    by 0x4EEBE9B: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.1)
==23949==    by 0x4EECC8A: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.1)
==23949==    by 0x4EDF55F: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.1)
==23949==    by 0x4EDF36F: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.1)
==23949==    by 0x4E475FE: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.1)
==23949==  Address 0x640d863 is 35 bytes inside a block of size 16,384 alloc'd
==23949==    at 0x4C2A987: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23949==    by 0x6FCD4E1: XOpenDisplay (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==23949==    by 0x4EEACB4: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.1)
==23949==    by 0x4EDF330: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.1)
==23949==    by 0x4E475FE: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.1)
==23949==    by 0x40488D: Game::game_loop() (Game.cpp:131)
==23949==    by 0x4067FC: void std::_Mem_fn_base<void (Game::*)(), true>::operator()<, void>(Game*) const (in /home/element/games/medieval_explorer/src/main)
==23949==    by 0x40676A: void std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)>::_M_invoke<0ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul>) (functional:1531)
==23949==    by 0x406684: std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)>::operator()() (functional:1520)
==23949==    by 0x406623: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)> >::_M_run() (thread:115)
==23949==    by 0x540D34F: execute_native_thread_routine (thread.cc:84)
==23949==    by 0x513E4A3: start_thread (in /usr/lib/libpthread-2.22.so)
==23949==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==23949==    at 0x6FD87C0: XStoreColors (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==23949== 
==23949== Invalid read of size 4
==23949==    at 0x40266A: GameWindow::get_pixel_color(SDL_Surface*, int, int) (GameWindow.cpp:174)
==23949==    by 0x40418C: CollisionEngine::collision_check_wall(GameState*, Character*) (CollisionEngine.cpp:83)
==23949==    by 0x404022: CollisionEngine::collision_check_player(GameState*) (CollisionEngine.cpp:35)
==23949==    by 0x403F4C: CollisionEngine::collision_check(GameState*) (CollisionEngine.cpp:12)
==23949==    by 0x404C1B: Game::advance_actual_state() (Game.cpp:276)
==23949==    by 0x40490A: Game::game_loop() (Game.cpp:145)
==23949==    by 0x4067FC: void std::_Mem_fn_base<void (Game::*)(), true>::operator()<, void>(Game*) const (in /home/element/games/medieval_explorer/src/main)
==23949==    by 0x40676A: void std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)>::_M_invoke<0ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul>) (functional:1531)
==23949==    by 0x406684: std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)>::operator()() (functional:1520)
==23949==    by 0x406623: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)> >::_M_run() (thread:115)
==23949==    by 0x540D34F: execute_native_thread_routine (thread.cc:84)
==23949==    by 0x513E4A3: start_thread (in /usr/lib/libpthread-2.22.so)
==23949==  Address 0x63b2a10 is 0 bytes after a block of size 96 alloc'd
==23949==    at 0x4C2A987: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23949==    by 0x4EDA0FF: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.1)
==23949==    by 0x403800: Graphics::surface_copy(SDL_Surface*) (Graphics.cpp:80)
==23949==    by 0x4035EC: Graphics::get_map(GID) (Graphics.cpp:31)
==23949==    by 0x401FC8: GameWindow::GameWindow(Graphics*, GameState*) (GameWindow.cpp:15)
==23949==    by 0x404511: Game::Game() (Game.cpp:47)
==23949==    by 0x404C45: main (main.cpp:39)
==23949== 
==23949== Invalid read of size 4
==23949==    at 0x40266A: GameWindow::get_pixel_color(SDL_Surface*, int, int) (GameWindow.cpp:174)
==23949==    by 0x4022C3: GameWindow::draw_walls(SDL_Surface*, GameState*) (GameWindow.cpp:83)
==23949==    by 0x402041: GameWindow::draw(SDL_Surface*, GameState*) (GameWindow.cpp:24)
==23949==    by 0x404A16: Game::display_game_window() (Game.cpp:177)
==23949==    by 0x404916: Game::game_loop() (Game.cpp:149)
==23949==    by 0x4067FC: void std::_Mem_fn_base<void (Game::*)(), true>::operator()<, void>(Game*) const (in /home/element/games/medieval_explorer/src/main)
==23949==    by 0x40676A: void std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)>::_M_invoke<0ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul>) (functional:1531)
==23949==    by 0x406684: std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)>::operator()() (functional:1520)
==23949==    by 0x406623: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)> >::_M_run() (thread:115)
==23949==    by 0x540D34F: execute_native_thread_routine (thread.cc:84)
==23949==    by 0x513E4A3: start_thread (in /usr/lib/libpthread-2.22.so)
==23949==    by 0x5CD313C: clone (in /usr/lib/libc-2.22.so)
==23949==  Address 0x63b2a10 is 0 bytes after a block of size 96 alloc'd
==23949==    at 0x4C2A987: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23949==    by 0x4EDA0FF: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.1)
==23949==    by 0x403800: Graphics::surface_copy(SDL_Surface*) (Graphics.cpp:80)
==23949==    by 0x4035EC: Graphics::get_map(GID) (Graphics.cpp:31)
==23949==    by 0x401FC8: GameWindow::GameWindow(Graphics*, GameState*) (GameWindow.cpp:15)
==23949==    by 0x404511: Game::Game() (Game.cpp:47)
==23949==    by 0x404C45: main (main.cpp:39)
==23949== 
==23949== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==23949==    at 0x40444C: CollisionEngine::handle_wall_collision(GameState*, Character*) (CollisionEngine.cpp:155)
==23949==    by 0x40404D: CollisionEngine::collision_check_player(GameState*) (CollisionEngine.cpp:39)
==23949==    by 0x403F4C: CollisionEngine::collision_check(GameState*) (CollisionEngine.cpp:12)
==23949==    by 0x404C1B: Game::advance_actual_state() (Game.cpp:276)
==23949==    by 0x40490A: Game::game_loop() (Game.cpp:145)
==23949==    by 0x4067FC: void std::_Mem_fn_base<void (Game::*)(), true>::operator()<, void>(Game*) const (in /home/element/games/medieval_explorer/src/main)
==23949==    by 0x40676A: void std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)>::_M_invoke<0ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul>) (functional:1531)
==23949==    by 0x406684: std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)>::operator()() (functional:1520)
==23949==    by 0x406623: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)> >::_M_run() (thread:115)
==23949==    by 0x540D34F: execute_native_thread_routine (thread.cc:84)
==23949==    by 0x513E4A3: start_thread (in /usr/lib/libpthread-2.22.so)
==23949==    by 0x5CD313C: clone (in /usr/lib/libc-2.22.so)
==23949==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==23949==    at 0x4C29118: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23949==    by 0x404C3A: main (main.cpp:39)
==23949== 
==23949== Invalid read of size 1
==23949==    at 0x40444C: CollisionEngine::handle_wall_collision(GameState*, Character*) (CollisionEngine.cpp:155)
==23949==    by 0x40404D: CollisionEngine::collision_check_player(GameState*) (CollisionEngine.cpp:39)
==23949==    by 0x403F4C: CollisionEngine::collision_check(GameState*) (CollisionEngine.cpp:12)
==23949==    by 0x404C1B: Game::advance_actual_state() (Game.cpp:276)
==23949==    by 0x40490A: Game::game_loop() (Game.cpp:145)
==23949==    by 0x4067FC: void std::_Mem_fn_base<void (Game::*)(), true>::operator()<, void>(Game*) const (in /home/element/games/medieval_explorer/src/main)
==23949==    by 0x40676A: void std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)>::_M_invoke<0ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul>) (functional:1531)
==23949==    by 0x406684: std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)>::operator()() (functional:1520)
==23949==    by 0x406623: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)> >::_M_run() (thread:115)
==23949==    by 0x540D34F: execute_native_thread_routine (thread.cc:84)
==23949==    by 0x513E4A3: start_thread (in /usr/lib/libpthread-2.22.so)
==23949==    by 0x5CD313C: clone (in /usr/lib/libc-2.22.so)
==23949==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==23949== 
==23949== 
==23949== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==23949==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==23949==    at 0x40444C: CollisionEngine::handle_wall_collision(GameState*, Character*) (CollisionEngine.cpp:155)
==23949==    by 0x40404D: CollisionEngine::collision_check_player(GameState*) (CollisionEngine.cpp:39)
==23949==    by 0x403F4C: CollisionEngine::collision_check(GameState*) (CollisionEngine.cpp:12)
==23949==    by 0x404C1B: Game::advance_actual_state() (Game.cpp:276)
==23949==    by 0x40490A: Game::game_loop() (Game.cpp:145)
==23949==    by 0x4067FC: void std::_Mem_fn_base<void (Game::*)(), true>::operator()<, void>(Game*) const (in /home/element/games/medieval_explorer/src/main)
==23949==    by 0x40676A: void std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)>::_M_invoke<0ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul>) (functional:1531)
==23949==    by 0x406684: std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)>::operator()() (functional:1520)
==23949==    by 0x406623: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Game::*)()> (Game*)> >::_M_run() (thread:115)
==23949==    by 0x540D34F: execute_native_thread_routine (thread.cc:84)
==23949==    by 0x513E4A3: start_thread (in /usr/lib/libpthread-2.22.so)
==23949==    by 0x5CD313C: clone (in /usr/lib/libc-2.22.so)
==23949==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==23949==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==23949==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==23949==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==23949==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==23949== 
==23949== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23949==     in use at exit: 52,118,160 bytes in 43,092 blocks
==23949==   total heap usage: 111,139 allocs, 68,047 frees, 623,656,015 bytes allocated
==23949== 
==23949== LEAK SUMMARY:
==23949==    definitely lost: 16,911,956 bytes in 147 blocks
==23949==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23949==      possibly lost: 26,050,169 bytes in 41,710 blocks
==23949==    still reachable: 9,156,035 bytes in 1,235 blocks
==23949==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==23949==                         stdstring          : 401 bytes in 6 blocks
==23949==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23949== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==23949== 
==23949== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==23949== ERROR SUMMARY: 351 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Here is the "handle_wall_collision" function where the code takes a segfault:

```
// character is in collision with walls, handle it
// only need to do one increment because the collision will be detected and handled again
void CollisionEngine::handle_wall_collision(GameState *game_state, Character *character){
    // move a character the opposite direction of their speed until there is no more collision
    // the until there is no more collision part is handled by the way this method is called
    // we know how far they have moved into the object is some multiple of their speed
    // get the sign of x_move_speed, y_move_speed
    int x_sign = (character->map_location->x_move_speed == 0) ? (0) : (character->map_location->x_move_speed/abs(character->map_location->x_move_speed));
    int y_sign = (character->map_location->y_move_speed == 0) ? (0) : (character->map_location->y_move_speed/abs(character->map_location->y_move_speed));

    // determine the direction of movement
    //if(abs(character->map_location->x_move_speed) > abs(character->map_location->y_move_speed)){
    if(this->is_previous_collision_x){
        character->map_location->x_location += -1*x_sign;
    }else{
        character->map_location->y_location += -1*y_sign;
    }

    //std::cout << "seg_fault_above" << std::flush;
}
```

Note, If I avoid using any member variables (basically anything which could be referenced by "this") than the code works fine.
I can use Member variables in constructor.

**Edit:**
Member this->is_previous_collision_x is initialized in the constructor:

```
CollisionEngine::CollisionEngine(){
    this->is_previous_collision_x = false;
}
```

This is the loop which calls the offending method:

```
// while there are collisions with the walls, handle them
do{
    wall_collision = collision_check_wall(actual_state, actual_state->get_player());

    if(wall_collision){
        //std::cout << " wall collision detected\n";
        handle_wall_collision(actual_state, actual_state->get_player());
    }
}while(wall_collision);
```

I'm using SDL2 library. I have made sure to use the methods provided by this library to destroy the textures/ surfaces /render I have made, but they still produce some of these errors.

Also importantly, Player is a Character.

**Edit**
I feel exceptionally dumb.
Game holds a *CollisionEngine as a private member
advance_actual_state() uses this pointer to call collision_engine->collision_check(game_state)

The issue was that this->collision_engine = new CollisionEngine()  was not being called in the constructor.

Comment: The error says you are accessing uninitialized memory. Did you initialize the member variables? If you think you did, show that code, there is something wrong with it.

Comment: What makes you think your "this" pointer is valid?  Look hard at the calling code.

Comment: Looks like you have more memory problems than that crash, possibly concurrency-related. It's almost certain that the root of the problem occurs much earlier. How are you creating that object?

Comment: what might cause the "this" pointer to become invalid?

Comment: @TimothyDee Some other code path that causes the object to be destroyed. Add logging in `~CollisionEngine`.

Comment: Which line is line 155?

Comment: if(this->is_previous_collision_x){ is line 155.

Comment: Then clearly the problem is that `this` is `0`. The bug is in whatever function called a member function on a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Access not within mapped region at address 0x0`

Notice the `0x0` there? That means you tried to dereference a NULL pointer. Add lots of asserts to your code to try to catch it. For example, add `assert (this != NULL);` at function entry points.

It could also be `character` or `character->mmap_location` that's NULL. Add asserts for everything.

Perhaps this will work:

```
void CollisionEngine::handle_wall_collision(GameState *game_state, Character *character){

 if (this == NULL)
     std::cerr << "CE:hwc, this is NULL" << std::endl;
 if (character == NULL)
     std::cerr << "CE:hwc character is NULL" << std::endl;
 if (character->map_location == NULL)
     std::cerr << "CE:hwc map_location is NULL" << std::Endl;

 // rest of code here
```

Comment: Runing thisn code returns:
"CE:hwc, this is NULL"

Comment: Then the problem is in the code that calls this code. It should definitely not be invoking `handle_wall_collision` on a NULL pointer. If it's called by a member of the same class, then the problem is in the caller of that function, probably `advance_actual_state`.